# Sum of Square Numbers

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve a task on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-square-numbers/description/), where I need to find if a positive integer is the sum of squares of two other integers. My solution is below, but it fails due to exceeding time limit.

```
var judgeSquareSum = function(c) {
    let output = false;
    for(let i = c; i >= 0; i--) {
      for(let y = 0; y <= i; y++) {
        let sum = i*i + y*y;
        if (sum == c) 
                output = true;
      }
    }

    return output;
};
```

How can I make this so that is efficient, and without two iterations?

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of computation, e.g. with the formula for a sum of n natural numbers https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm

Comment: Does 0 count as a integer, eg `0 * 0 + 0 * 0  === 0` or `0 * 0 + 3 * 3 === 9` ?

Comment: Apparently, it does.

Comment: Well then the very first test is `if(Math.sqrt(c) % 1 === 0) {return true}` will eliminate many iterations. Also a good number to start searching down from would be `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(c))` as it cant be greater than that.

Comment: What about some mathematics? [*"An integer greater than one can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if its prime decomposition contains no prime congruent to 3 (mod 4) raised to an odd power"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem)

Comment: You are not really asking for a code review of your current code, right? Perhaps you will get better answers at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You restrict the scope of the variables to the nearest enclosing scope with `let`,
which is good.

The use of whitespace is not consistent: `for(` vs `if (`.

The variable names seem a be arbitrary: Why `i` and `y`, and not
`a` and `b` as in the LeetCode problem description?

The first you can do to speed things up is to "early return":

```
var judgeSquareSum = function(c) {
    for(let i = c; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(let y = 0; y <= i; y++) {
            let sum = i*i + y*y;
            if (sum == c) 
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

There is no need to continue with the loops if a decomposition into a sum of
two squares has been found.

Now note that one integer in the decomposition determines the other. If we have
a test candidate \$ a \$  for  \$ c = a^2 + b^2 \$ then it suffices
to check if \$ \sqrt{c - a^2} \$  is an integer. Also we can assume that \$ a \le b \$,
which restricts the range of \$ a \$:

```
var judgeSquareSum = function(c) {
    let aMax = Math.sqrt(c/2);
    for (let a = 0; a <= aMax; a++) {
        let b = Math.sqrt(c - a * a);
        if (b === Math.round(b)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Only one loop instead of two nested loops now!

Further improvement is possible with the help of mathematics. As stated in
[Sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem),

> An integer greater than one can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if
>    its prime decomposition contains no prime congruent to 3 (mod 4) raised to an odd power.

So we need to determine if in the prime factorization
$$
  c = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_n^{e_n}
$$
there is a term \$ p_j^{e_j} \$ such that \$ p_i = 3 \bmod 4 \$
and \$ e_j \$ is odd.

This is more code, but very efficient for for large numbers, because

- the range of prime candidates \$ p \$ can be bounded by \$ \sqrt c \$, and
- once a prime factor is found, \$ c \$ can be *divided* by that factor, thus
  reducing the remaining number of iterations.

Here is a possible implementation, with more explaining comments inline:

```
var judgeSquareSum = function(c) {
    // Handle 0, 1, and 2 directly:
    if (c <= 2) {
        return true
    }
    // Remove even factors:
    while (c % 2 === 0) {
        c /= 2;
    }
    // Find odd prime factors:
    for (let p = 3; p <= Math.sqrt(c); p += 2) {
        if (c % p === 0) {
            // Determine exponent e of p in c:
            let e = 0;
            while (c % p === 0) {
                e += 1;
                c /= p; // Remove this prime factor
            }
            // Is it a prime congruent 4 (mod 3), raised to an odd power?
            if (p % 4 === 3 && e % 2 === 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // If c > 1 at this point then it is another prime factor:
    if (c % 4 === 3) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: A small change I would add is pre-calculating `Math.sqrt(c/2)` rather than calculating it on every iteration.

Comment: @MarcRohloff: You are right, thanks. (The final version intentionally re-calculates the bound because c becomes smaller during the iteration.)

Comment: Some optional untested 32-bit micro-optimizations to reduce the number of slow division operations: `p % 2` → `p & 1`, `p % 4` → `p & 3`, `c % p` followed by `c /= p` → might be able to get rid of the modulo by dividing first and checking the result for `isInteger`